# Graphics card doesn't know about driver

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card

I have a notebook with integrated and dedicated graphics card. I've reinstalled the system recently and tried to install driver for dedicated card (and integrated as well). The AMD self recognizing program had installed the driver (at least it seems like it did), but the card doesn't seem to know about the driver. To be more specific, when I disable the integrated card in Device Manager, everything behaves like without driver (I mean lowest resolution, no aero, etc.) I consider myself as quite experienced user, have never faced this problem though.

Comment: Give us a screenshot of your device manager.

Comment: Did you get the driver directly from AMD or from your notebook manufacturer?  Also, did you install all the other drivers as well (chipset, etc.)?

Comment: boboes Sorry, can't provide the screenshot of device manager, since it's notebook of a customer which he needs and I made it to work, I am solving distantly the rest. You would see both cards - dedicated and integrated (chip)

@Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I have installed the drivers directly from AMD, the rest - chipset, etc. from manufacturer.

Comment: After a complete system rebuild you will be having per configured drivers for your dedicated graphics card and hence the AMD card detected itself and it got installed. But to get the full usage of the card, please do download the latest driver from the manufacture (graphics) and while installation the notebook should be connected to the internet. After the successful installation the AMD card will be detected completely and it can be used.